# UnsupportedEncodingException When Parsing PDFs Android

Tags: android, pdf

I keep getting UnsupportedEncodingException errors everytime I try to parse a pdf in Android. Does anyone know why? I'm positive that my coding is correct. Most of the errors are Unicode Big Unmarked or MacRoman.

Here's the code...

```
public void parsePdf(URL pdf) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf.openStream());
    PdfTextExtractor pdfEx = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);
    try{
    System.out.println(pdfEx.getTextFromPage(1));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println(e.toString());

    }
```

This is the exception...
05-02 01:12:57.735: I/System.out(299): ExceptionConverter: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UnicodeBigUnmarked

Comment: Show your code!  And the stack trace(s).

Comment: Edited and added code and exception